# Emit data from Child to parent vue 3

Tags: vue.js, onclick, submit, emit

I have a **SearchBar.vue** child page with a form in this this code :

```
      <template>
      <div>
        <form class="search-bar" @submit.prevent="SearchMovies()">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Effectuez une recherche"
            v-model="search"
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="search-input"
            @click="$emit('get-movies', movies)"
          >
            CHERCHER
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>
```

And my **SearchMovies()** function looks like :

```
    setup() {
        const search = ref("");
        const movies = ref([]);

        function SearchMovies () {

          if (search.value != "") {
            
            fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL_CALL_TWO}${search.value}`)
              .then((response) => response.json())
              .then((data) => {
                movies.value = data.contents;
                search.value = "";
                console.log(
                  "Movies data from SearchBar.vue when fired up: ",
                  movies.value
                );

              });
          }

          this.$emit('get-movies', movies)

        }
```

This is how I have tried to add the emit line

```
              this.$emit('get-movies', movies)
```

And I receive the emitted data from **SearchMovies()** function to my parent **Home.vue** page like this :

```
    <template>

      <div>
        <router-link to="/" href="/"
          ><img class="logo-img" alt="App logo" src="../assets/logo.png"
        /></router-link>

        <SearchBar @get-movies="getMovies($event)" />

        <MovieList :movies="movies" />
      </div>
    </template>






      methods: {
        getMovies: function (movies) {
          (this.movies = movies),
            console.log("Movies data from Home.vue when fired up: ", 
            movies);
        },
      },
```

The problem is that I am not getting the **movies** data and when I console.log it in the **Home.vue** page

> ```
>     Movies data from Home.vue when fired up:  Proxy {}
> ```

Comment: Still didn't found any solutions, any one to help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your search bar, the @click event is never actually invoking the SearchMovies method. Try converting

```
<button type="submit" class="search-input" @click="searchMovies">...</button>
```

You're not exporting the function in your setup, at the bottom of setup

```
setup (_, {emit}) {
    const search = ref("")
    const movies = ref([])
    const SearchMovies = () => {
        const value = await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL_CALL_TWO}${search.value}`)
        const data = await value.json()
        movies.value = data.contents
        search.value = ""
        console.log("Movies data from SearchBar.vue when fired up: ", movies.value);
        emit('get-movies', movies.value)
    }
    return { search, movies, SearchMovies }
}
```

In your fetch statement, you're going to have some async code issue, the fetch statement will run, but then it will skip the await callbacks in favor of doing this.$emit. I'd convert it to
Then, finally, I wouldn't catch the value in Home.vue with

```
<SearchBar @get-movies="getMovies($event)" />
```

Instead, just use `@get-movies="getMovies"` You don't actually need make it call a function, it will just do it on it's own and I find trying to use the event bus causes confusion sometimes. You only need to use it if you have specific data from the template you could pass into it, like in a v-for loop you could pass in the specific object. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything so you can better understand *why* it's built like this.

```
<template>
      <div class="search-bar">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Effectuez une recherche"
            v-model="search"
          />
          <button
            class="search-input"
            @click="SearchMovies"
          >
            CHERCHER
          </button>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: Tank you very much for your answer. I implemented all what you said, but it still dones't work, Now i am not getting anything after the click the page reloads quickly without getting any data ! I have added the Async / await to searchMovies function ..

Comment: If the beginning I was trying to emit data with onSubmit in the input form and not with a click event but now i just did @click="searchMovies" as you suggested

Comment: Part of this is because I wasn't aware that you were using form logic for this. Truth be told, I find using forms are archaic in comparison to using modern fetch apis. If it were me, I'd remove the form element, make the css class on the div instead, and convert the button from a submit, to just a button.

Comment: To clarify, part of why I think forms are old is because when forms are submitted, it reloads the page. Which is something a single page application should never do.

Comment: Yeah but what can be the solution for me using the form ? Changing the form is not a solution for me now.

Comment: I added some code to the bottom of the answer, showing how you could just remove the form.

Comment: TypeError: this.emit is not a function

Comment: change to this.$emit my bad

Comment: Thank you but still same error message :  TypeError: this.$emit is not a function :/

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.$emit is not a function

Comment: I googled it and people say you should use Arrow Functions !

Comment: My function is lookin like : 

  `setup() {
    const search = ref("");
    const movies = ref([]);

    async function searchMovies() {
      if (search.value != "") {
       // DoSomething
        this.$emit("get-movies", movies.value);
      }
    }

    return {
      search,
      movies,
      searchMovies,
    };
  },`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242115/discussion-between-issayah-and-mourad-over-flow).